# I'm curious about how to analyze what data is coming and going from equipment that provides thinning communication

Tags: serial-port, pyserial

My company uses a broadcasting device called PAC-5300. The device provides serial communication. However, there is no data manual to send for serial(RS-232C) communication. In this case, how do I resolve it?

I'm sorry. I've been in serial communication, and I can't figure out how to solve this case.

The equipment is expensive, so we don't have it in the company right now. But I'm analyzing it with tools like WireShark or looking for other tools.